# WPF: How do I initialize a property to be animated from the trigger that's animating it?

Tags: wpf, animation, datatrigger

I have a Grid in my view whose "visibility" is determined by whether a collection has more than one element.  That Grid needs to be animated expanding and collapsing as elements are added and removed.  I've written a DataTrigger to do that which works fine.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyCollection.Count, Converter={StaticResource IsLessThanConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetName="MyCollapsingGrid" TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.2"
                                EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExpoEaseInOut}"
                                To="0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetName="MyCollapsingGrid" TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.2"
                            EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExpoEaseInOut}"
                            To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

I'm initializing the LayoutTransform for my Grid to a default ScaleTransform

```
<Grid x:Name="MyCollapsingGrid">
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform />
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
</Grid>
```

When my view is initialized with a collection that has two elements and I remove one, the Grid animates collapsing correctly.  However, when I initialize my view with a collection with one element, it shows the Grid briefly as it plays the collapse animation.  Since I'm already using a trigger to do this animation, how do I initialize the Grid's LayoutTransform to have a ScaleX of 0 when my collection only has one element so that I don't see the collapse animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to bind `ScaleTransform.ScaleY` property with mode set to `OneTime`:

```
<ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding Path=MyCollection.Count,
                                 Converter={StaticResource TheMissingConverter},
                                 ConverterParameter=2,
                                 Mode=OneTime}" />
```

The only piece missing from this picture is the converter, which should work similarly to your `IsLessThanConverter` except it should return `1` and `0` instead `false` and `true` respectively (scale should be `1` if count is not less than `2`, and `0` otherwise). Note that it is important to set the mode to `OneTime` (with mode set to `OneWay` I experienced unexpected behavior in certain circumstances while testing this solution).

Comment: That is perfect.  I assumed this would be a common animation initialization issue (and it sort of is as far as dependency property value precedence) but instead it's just a plain old value initialization issue.  Thanks for the answer!